# How to get the dragon to fight me

Tags: candy-box-2

In Candy Box 2 all of my friends end up fighting the dragon, but he won't fight me.
Is there something I'm supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

The dragon's purpose is to give you quests, not to be fought. After trying to attack it for a bit, you'll be able to talk to it instead.